# How to remove certain prefix using regex

Tags: regex

My User data can come in any of the following 3 ways -

user="dc\AAA",       user="BBB",      user=CCCC,

Now, the bottom two I am able to extract it easily but issue comes when user data has an additional prefix of "dc" to it

I am trying to remove that prefix using regex and format all user data in single regex as below, but the unable to do so

user=AAA user=BBB user=CCC

Can someone please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This regex should do the work: `(?:.*\\)?(.*)`.
Let's split this regex into parts:

- `(?:    )` - A non-capturing group
- `.*\\` - Any characters many times, trailing by backslash
- `?` (after the brackets) indicates the data in the brackets may occur once or not at all
- `(.*)` Any characters

Overall - Capturing the data after the backslash if exists

I suggest using [this amazing website](https://regex101.com/) for trying regex

Comment: Thanks, that was helpful. I've found additional two ways in which users can come in my data like user=ad/AAA & user=PQR\" , among this, for 1st one I am able to extract correctly but for user=PQR\" , It is just matching \" and i want it to match user=PQR without any \". Here is my regex https://regex101.com/r/IxWSAu/1 , would it be possible to do this within this regex itself ?